# Python Extracting numbers and adding them from a list

Tags: python, list, numbers

I have a list of strings:

```
[' 86 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' MV\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', '  15.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0  miles  \n', ' 86 miles\n', '.7 miles', '5. miles']`
```

So there are numbers in different formats:

`86` `.7` `5.` `0.0`

Followed by strings of text.

I need to add together all the numbers in this list.

The adding part is obviously easy, but how do I get only the numbers out into a list of their own?

Comment: "int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()" should extract all of your numbers into a list and you can then add the values of the list

Comment: @thefragileomen except it won't :)

Comment: @thefragileomen that won't work for floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> elements = [' 86 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' MV\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' 15.0 m iles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles \n', ' 86 miles\n', ' .7 miles', ' 5. miles']
>>> _re_digits = re.compile(r"(-?(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+)))")
>>> digits = []
>>> for element in elements:
    digits += [ float(n) for n in _re_digits.findall(element)]


>>> digits
[86.0, 43.0, 0.0, 43.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 86.0, 0.7, 5.0]
>>> sum(digits)
278.7
```

Comment: Of all the answers, I think this one works the best for me. Thank, a lot. :D

Comment: Quick question, is there a way to modify this, so that it catches `'.7 miles'` as well? Right now, it catches it as 7 miles.

Comment: @MikeVaughan I updated the answer. The regex is a little but more ugly, but it's because of the non matching parenthesis. The idea is that you have to dissociate the cases: either some digits, optionally followed by a dot optionally followed by digits, or a dot followed by digits. trying to merge them two will lead in matching single dots.

Comment: 'trying to merge the two will lead to matching single dots' is the problem I had when I tried myself. I'm just not very good with regex. I can do some simple things, but this is just a lot. Haha. Thanks again. :D

Comment: I'll update the question to include these new string items, as well. For anyone who stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 1):

We can join all strings in one, use a regular expression to extract all numbers, and then add them:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = [
    ' 86 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', '  MV\n', ' 0.0 miles\n',
    ' 43 miles\n', '  15.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n',
    ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0  miles  \n', ' 86 miles\n'
]
>>> sum(map(float, re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", "".join(l))))
273.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the numbers as floats:

```
miles = [' 86 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' MV\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', '  15.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0  miles  \n', ' 86 miles\n']

total = 0.0
for s in miles:
    for t in s.split():
        try:
            total += float(t)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your list to a list with numbers using regular expression:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+")

l = [' 86 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' MV\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 43 miles\n', ' 15.0 m iles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles\n', ' 0.0 miles \n', ' 86 miles\n']

numbers = [float(regex.findall(x)[0]) for x in l if regex.findall(x) != [] ]
>>> [86.0, 43.0, 0.0, 43.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 86.0]
```